# Remove filter for received notification

Tags: android

I've firebase Messaging Service code in which a notification title is checked and if it contains certain Text & is on certain page in webview, it shows a Toast & refreshes page.

Now the thing is I want to remove below line which I called as text filter:

```
if (title.contains("Added")) {
```

Can anyone tell how to modify below code?

```
public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        final String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();



        if (title.contains("Added")) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Log.d("webUrl",""+MainActivity.mWebview.getUrl());

                            if(MainActivity.mWebview.getUrl().contains("http://example.com")) {
                                Toast.makeText(FcmMessagingService.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                MainActivity.reLoad();
                            }
                            }
                    }
            );

     }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", "kh");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Uri sounduri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon);
            notificationBuilder.setSound(sounduri);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.cancel(0);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


        }


    }


}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "retain page filter only."? where is your page filter?

Comment: @FerdousAhamed updated question. I want to remove "if (title.contains("Added"))
"

Comment: what is your requirements actually? what do you want with the value of title and message?

Comment: @FerdousAhamed I want to check if user is on page "www.example.com" if yes then I want to show him Toast otherwise he should get a push notification. In above code, it checks for title("ADDED"). I want to remove title check.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    if(MainActivity.mWebview.getUrl().contains("http://example.com")) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Log.d("webUrl",""+MainActivity.mWebview.getUrl());
                        Toast.makeText(FcmMessagingService.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        MainActivity.reLoad();
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", "kh");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri sounduri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(sounduri);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.cancel(0);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Giving error - Method getUrl must be called from UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker thread